Direction of propagation of extraordinary wave inside a birefringent medium
I am reading Optics by Ajoy Ghatak, in which the author explains the phenomenon of double refraction in a calcite crystal using Huygens' principle. My query is in the analysis of the case of normal incidence of a wave on the crystal surface.

The author states the following regarding the o and e-waves:

For both waves, the space and time dependence of the vectors $\mathbf{E}$, $\mathbf{D}$, $\mathbf{B}$ and $\mathbf{H}$ can be assumed to be of the form $e^{i(\mathbf{\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}-\omega t)}$, where $\mathbf{k}$ denotes the propagation vector and represents the direction normal to the phase fronts.

My question is regarding the following observation he makes about the above figure:

It is to be noted that the direction of $\mathbf{k}$ is the same for both o- and e-waves i.e., both are along $BO$. However, if we have a narrow beam incident as $AB$, then while the ordinary ray will propagate along $BO$, the extraordinary ray will propagate in a different direction $BE$, as shown in the figure.

What exactly is the direction of the e-wave inside the medium? If it is given by k (which also satisfies the condition $\mathbf{D}\cdot\mathbf{k}=0 $ i.e. the polarization is perpendicular to the propagation direction); then what does the 'diagonal' propagation given by BE represent? How does the e-wave shift if $\mathbf{k}$ is always pointing downwards? Does it have to something to do with the Poynting vector of the wave? Or maybe I am confusing between waves and rays? Any help is appreciated.
